# CV symbol position alignment problem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, altacv

I'm using these templates as baseline:

- https://es.overleaf.com/articles/pratham-tibrewals-cv/xbckppvktddd
- https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/recreating-business-insiders-cv-of-marissa-mayer/gtqfpbwncfvp

And this section (output from my code, which is the template above modified):

[image]

Is built with this:

```
\cvsection{Professional Experience}
\cveventt{Role name}{Company name}{jan 2020 - feb 2021}{City}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Responsabilities
\end{itemize}

\divider

\cveventt{Role name 2}{Very long company name}{jan 2020 - feb 2021}{Long name city}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Responsabilities
\end{itemize}
\divider
```

The `\cvevent` command:

```
\newcommand{\cveventt}[4]{%
  {\large\color{emphasis}#1\par}
  \smallskip\normalsize
  \ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{
  \textbf{\color{accent}#2}}
  \ifstrequal{#3}{}{}{{\small\makebox[0.5\linewidth][c]
  {\faCalendar\hspace{0.5em}#3}}}%
  \ifstrequal{#4}{}{}{{\small\makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]
  {\faMapMarker\hspace{0.5em}#4}}}\par
  \medskip\normalsize
}
```

I'm trying to get the dates and the city aligned no matter the long of the text. The city should be right-centered and the dates middle-centered, because currently it depends on how long is the company name. Specifically speaking, I'm trying to:

- The city symbol starts at a specific position right-centered, so no matter how long the city name is, it will always start at the same point.
- The calendar symbol starts at a specific position middle-centered, so no matter how long the calendar dates/names are, every date will start at the same position.
- The length of the dates shouldn't move the position of the city symbol, and the company name shouldn't move neither the calendar symbol position or the city symbol position

Is this possible, given the construction of the `\cvevent` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code for `\cveventtt` using parboxes. Adjust the relative size of the parboxes to your liking.

[image: a]

```
\newcommand{\cveventtt}[4]{%
    {\large\color{emphasis}#1\par}
    \smallskip\normalsize
    \ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{%
    \parbox[t]{0.3\columnwidth}{\textbf{\color{accent}#2}}\hfill
    }
    \ifstrequal{#3}{}{}{%
        \small\faCalendar\hspace{0.5em}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr0.3\columnwidth-1em}{#3}\hfill
    }%
    \ifstrequal{#4}{}{}{%
        \small\faMapMarker\hspace{0.5em}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr0.2\columnwidth-1em}{#4}
    }\par
    \medskip\normalsize
}
```

This code makes it easy to see the boxes and the space between them.

```
\newcommand{\cveventtt}[4]{%
\fboxsep=0pt % tight fboxes
{\large\color{emphasis}#1\par}
\smallskip\normalsize
\ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{%
    \fbox{\parbox[t]{0.3\columnwidth}{\textbf{\color{accent}#2}}}\hfill
}
\ifstrequal{#3}{}{}{%
    \fbox{\small\faCalendar\hspace{0.5em}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr0.3\columnwidth-1em}{#3}}\hfill
}%
\ifstrequal{#4}{}{}{%
    \fbox{\small\faMapMarker\hspace{0.5em}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr0.2\columnwidth-1em}{#4}}
}\par
\medskip\normalsize
}
```

[image: b]

There are three boxes. In this example the first has a width of `0.3\columnwidth`, the second of `0.3\columnwidth` and the third a width of  `0.2\columnwidth`. The remaining width, up to `2\columnwidth` is equally distributed between them by the two `\hfill` (`0.1\columnwidth` each).

So you can change the width of the individual boxes making sure that the total width is one `\columnwidth` and/or you can replace the  `\hfill` with a fix space like

`\hspace{0.06\columnwidth}` for the first and `\hspace{0.14\columnwidth}` for the second.

Using the fraction of the column width to set the widths makes it easier to verify that the total is exactly one column width.

Comment: It worked! Could you explain a bit what parameters should I change if I want to change (1) the position or (2) the length for each box?

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your feedback!. I added a short explanation at the end of the answer.