# Independent format and position inside another command

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, altacv

I'm using these templates as baseline:

- https://es.overleaf.com/articles/pratham-tibrewals-cv/xbckppvktddd
- https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/recreating-business-insiders-cv-of-marissa-mayer/gtqfpbwncfvp

And this section (output from my code, which is the template above modified):

[image]

It's built with this:

```
\cveventt{Role Name XXX \textit{common tech stack:}}{Company Name}{Jan 2021 -- Oct 2022}{Location}
```

The `\cveventt` command:

```
\newcommand{\cveventt}[4]{%
    {\large\color{emphasis}#1\par}
    \smallskip\normalsize
    \ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{%
    \parbox[t]{0.31\columnwidth}{\textbf{\color{accent}#2}}\hfill
    }
    \ifstrequal{#3}{}{}{%
        \small\faCalendar\hspace{0.5em}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr0.315\columnwidth-1em}{#3}\hfill
    }%
    \ifstrequal{#4}{}{}{%
        \small\faMapMarker\hspace{0.5em}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr0.255\columnwidth-1em}{#4}
    }\par
    \medskip\normalsize
}
```

I'm trying that the `\textit{common tech stack:}` part from the image above is formatted independently from "Role Name XXX". Specifically, `common tech stack` should be:

- Smaller, italic, lighter, highlighted, and maybe a clear blue font.. so at the end, it is a completely **independent format**.
- Its **position should be independent** of the number of characters of `Role Name XXX`, as each role has different names which mean different lengths. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643543/cv-symbol-position-alignment-problem) solution is a "boxing" approach to another problem, which could fit this one. However, I'm struggling that I'm trying this inside another command.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did the provided answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defined a new 5-argument command (some could be empty)

`\cveventv{<role>}{<sub role>}{<company came>}{<date interval>}{<location>}`

Using

```
\newcommand{\fmtRole}{<font and color>} 

\newcommand{\fmtSubRole}{<font and color>}
```

the first two entries can be formatted independently.

Created with (add before `\begin{document}`)

```
\newcommand{\fmtRole}{\large\color{red}} % format "Role" <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\fmtSubRole}{\normalsize\itshape\color{blue}} % format "SubRole" <<<<<<<<<<<

\newcommand{\cveventv}[5]{%
{{\fmtRole#1}\hspace{0.5em}\ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{\fmtSubRole#2}\par}
\smallskip\normalsize
\ifstrequal{#3}{}{}{}{%
    \parbox[t]{0.30\linewidth}{\textbf{\color{accent}#3}}\hfill
}%
\ifstrequal{#4}{}{}{
    \small\faCalendar\hspace{0.5em}\parbox[t]{0.30\linewidth}{#4}\hfill
}%
\ifstrequal{#5}{}{}{%
    \small\faMapMarker\hspace{0.5em}\parbox[t]{0.2\linewidth}{#5}
}\par
\medskip\normalsize
}
```

and

```
\cveventv{Role name XXX and ZZZ}{common tech stack:}{Company Name}{Jan 2021 -- Oct 2022}{Location}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Responsabilities
\end{itemize}
```

[image: a]

As alternative, and having defined `\fmtRole` and `\fmtSubRole`
this will also work

```
\cveventt{{\fmtRole Role name XXX and ZZZ} \space {\fmtSubRole common tech stack:}}{Company Name}{Jan 2021 -- Oct 2022}{Location}
```